# Hive: Select * command is not working similar to RDBMS

Tags: hive, hiveql

I installed **apache hive-0.9.0** and start executing some basic commands and i found one abnormal behavior in select* command.  In select statement after * any random characters are allowed in hive but in **RDBMS** its not allowed.  I am not sure its expected behavior or bug in hive. Could some please confirm?

In the below query "abcdef" is random characters.

**In RDBMS(oracle):**

```
select *abcdef from mytable;
```

**Output:**

> ERROR prepare() failed with: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

**In Hive**:

```
select *abcdef from mytable;
```

**Output:**
Query worked fine and display all the records of mytable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got response from apache hive committe. Its a indeed bug in hive. They filed a improvement ticket for this issue
Jira Ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8155

Answer (score 0):

In RDBMS,select is followed by column name/* , but in HIVE,it may be column name/*/any regular expression(partitions) .

Go through this link 
http://www.qubole.com/5-tips-for-efficient-hive-queries/
it provides whole description